# Why cant i import from functions from another folders?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, import

I cannot import from another folders.

SO here is my tree.

```
(venv) ma1lor@ma1lor:~/test$ tree
.
├── asd
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── message.py
└── sad
    ├── __init__.py
    └── main.py

2 directories, 4 files
```

in `main.py`:

```py
from asd.message import message_func
from asd.message import email


print(message_func())
print(email)
```

in `message.py`:

```
def message_func():
    return 'hello , world'

email =43
```

this problem is not only on this project, its on everything. not only on `linux` but also on `windows` (I have 2 OSs)

I was trying to import function from another folder but didn't work.

Comment: could you add the **full** error traceback?

Comment: The simplest solution is to move *main.py* into the parent directory of *asd/sad*. In general, don't ever put *main.py* inside the package tree itself - always put it in the directory *containing* the top-level package.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to have the two packages be part of one single package, then put both directories in a single package directory, add a `__init__.py` in the base directory, then use an intra-package import. For example:

```
.
├── my_great_package
       |
       ├── __init__.py
       ├── asd
       │   ├── __init__.py
       │   └── message.py
       └── sad
           ├── __init__.py
           └── main.py


from ..asd.message import message_func, email
```

If your intention is to have `ads` and `sad` as two separate packages, then your imports are correct. *But*, then it depends on how you execute things. If you did

```
cd sad
python main.py
```

That would be incorrect: don't execute a file from within the package itself. Go to the root directory of the packages (`.` in your example), then execute

```
python sad/main.py
```

Now, Python will look from the current directory, `.`, for packages that are imported. When in the `sad` directory, Python does not go up a directory level to search for a neighbouring package like `asd`.

With the package - subpackage structure, you go up even one further:

```
python my_great_package/sad/main.py
```

---

*But you should *not* have an executable inside a package directory* (which basically is any directory with an `__init__.py` file). If you write an executable file ("script" as some people will call it), locate that *outside* of any package directory. The package files should contain re-usable functions, and the executable should import the package and call those functions.

You can even put scripts in a separate directory at the root level, say, `scripts/`, and run them from there. Probably as `script/something.py`; if you run them inside the `scripts` directory, you probably need to your `PYTHONPATH` (or first install the package with e.g. `pip install -e .`, but if you can avoid using `PYTHONPATH`, that's all the better: first rely on the default Python package & import finding, that makes your setup more portable, only then start tweaking the environment.